# How to preserve method parameters on every exception

Tags: c#, exception

For every possible exception I would like to include some information’s.
This information’s are parameters of method where exception happened.

What is best practice to preserve this information’s?

Maybe something like this?

```
private object TestMethod(object value1, object value2)
{
    try
    {
        object res = null;
        // complex some logic with many possible exceptions.
        return res;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception($"value1 = {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value1)}, value1 = {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value1)}", e);
    }
}
```

### Edit:

My solution:

Example how to use:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]MachineConfigurationDto machineDto)
    {
        try
        {
            // Some complex logic
            // . . .
            return new OkResult();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.AddExceptionParameter(this, nameof(machineDto), machineDto.ToJson());
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Exception helper:

```
public static class ExceptionHelper
    {
        public static Exception AddExceptionParameter<T>(this Exception ex, object currentClass, string key, T value, [CallerMemberName]string methodName = "") where T : struct
        {
            return ex.AddExceptionParameter(currentClass, methodName, key, value.ToString());
        }

        public static Exception AddExceptionParameter(this Exception ex, object currentClass, string key, string value, [CallerMemberName]string methodName = "")
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                value = "null";
            }

            if (currentClass == null)
            {
                currentClass = "No class";
            }

            if (methodName == null)
            {
                methodName = "No method";
            }

            if (key == null)
            {
                key = "No key";
            }

            var className = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                className = currentClass.GetType().Name;
            }
            catch
            {
                className = "No class name";
            }

            ex.Data.Add($"{className}.{methodName} : {key}", value);
            return ex;
        }
    }
```

ToJson method:

```
 public static class JsonContentExtension
    {
        public static string ToJson(this object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
            }
            catch
            {
                return $"Object {obj.ToString()} is not serializable.";
            }
        }
    }
```

How to log details:

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
            var message = LogExceptionData(context.Exception.Data, context.Exception.Message);
            _logger.LogError(1, context.Exception, message);
            // . . .
    }

private string LogExceptionData(IDictionary data, string message)
        {
            if (message == null)
            {
                message = "No message";
            }

            if (data == null || data.Count == 0)
            {
                return message;
            }

            var errorData = $"{message}{Environment.NewLine}";
            errorData += $"Method parameters:{Environment.NewLine}";
            var i = 1;
            foreach (DictionaryEntry item in data)
            {
                var key = item.Key ?? "null";
                var value = item.Value ?? "null";
                errorData += $"[{i}] => {key} = {value}{Environment.NewLine}";
                i++;
            }
            errorData += $"Details:";

            return errorData;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, looks like that should work (if you replace `value1` with `value2` the second time). What is your question? Do you understand that proper (unit) testing would alleviate the need for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First point, it is not best practice to throw System.Exception from your code. You should create custom exception type.

Second, You can use Exception.Data property to pass more information with exception (ex in your case parameter details). Hope this help.

```
catch (Exception e)
    {
        // If using general exception    
        var customException = new CustomException();
        customException.Data.Add(nameof(value1), JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value1))
         throw customException;
    }
```

Or

```
catch (Exception e)
    {
        // If using general exception    
         e.Data.Add(nameof(value1), JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value1))
         throw e; 
    }
```

Should not throw System.Exception, System.SystemException, System.NullReferenceException, or System.IndexOutOfRangeException intentionally from your own source code.